# Keras.util.to_categorical show unexpected behaviour

Tags: keras

Keras .To_Categorical shows unexpected behavior:

Contrary to documentation in https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical
Specifying dtype returns an error

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

labels= np.array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
to_categorical(labels,dtype='int32')
```

produce:

```
TypeError: to_categorical() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is in the [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py), but the issue is that the documentation corresponds to the github master version, while you don't that version installed. You most likely have a keras release installed.

Currently there is no Keras release that contains the commits for this parameter.